# How to make Standalone Windows form application?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2008

can anyone tell me how to make standalone of windows forms application.

I have made a simple GUI and have written a simple code for the same,

Now I want to publish it as standalone desktop application, can anybody tell me how to do that?

I have used visual studio 2008 and wrote the code in c++.

Comment: In project properties page, take a look at `Publish` tab.

Comment: The is no publishing tab, I tried to do it by adding Setup project, but I am getting error

Comment: There is a publish tab. In solution explorer Right click on project node and select properties, in properties page, go to publish tab.